# Transition properties not working when toggle HTML element class for size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just a simple CSS and jQuery function to ease the transition when removing a class. I have tried using Jquery too, nothing seems to work. Been through at least a dozen attempts, any ideas?
jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.review-block', function(){
    $(this).find(".review-body").toggleClass('small');
 }); 
});
```

CSS

```
.review-body{
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
     transition: all 1s ease;
}
.small{
    max-height: 125px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="review-body small">
  //TEXT HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Your `.review-body` has no `max-height` defined, so it will not be transitioned because there is no pixel value to transition from.

Comment: yes, your right, when setting the max height to a large number (larger than i would ever need to go) it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why no transition is observed, is because in `.review-body` there is no explicit `max-height` set, which means it uses the initial value of `auto`. You can't transition between a non-pixel value (e.g. `auto`, `100%`...) to a set pixel value.

A solution will be to give `.review-body` a larger that necessary `max-height` value in pixels, so that CSS transition will still work without cutting of the content inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add that `transition` property to both classes. Check out this codepen from MDN: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true

Comment: just tried it, doesnt work. goes instantly. If I set a max height on both, it works, but for some reason it cannot transition to auto?